# Power BI Desktop change count format of numbers

Tags: format, powerbi, decimal, powerbi-desktop

can someone tell me where i can change the format of "counted" numbers in a table visual? I'm talking about the "count" and "count in %" numbers. I want to change the "count" to have a thousands separator and the "count in %" to show only 1 decimal, instead of two.

These are not values from my database, they are generated via the "count" function of Power BI in table visuals.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

[image: thousand separator and one decimal in table view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the % value: if this is a table or a matrix, use the format panel and go to Field Formatting, select the field in the dropdown and type the number of decimal places.

[image]

For the total value (Anzahl), make sure you don't use the implicit measure that Power BI generates automatically. Instead, define your own measure, even if it is just a simple count or sum. Then with that measure selected, you can use the format ribbon to format the measure to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me a lot :-) Have a nice day!